# KotlinPoet how to get TypeName of generated class

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

I want to use a class generated with TypeSpec.classBuilder as a property in another class that I am generating. But for this I need to get a TypeName and I cannot find a way to access it. Only from the superclass. Anyone knows a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You should be perfectly fine with using `ClassName` there.
And the easiest way of obtaining the `ClassName` is to pass the `package` and the `name` of the generated type:

```
ClassName("your.package.here", "NameOfType")
```

You can see [here](https://github.com/blipinsk/butterknife-ktx/blob/5c2151eee0681aecc5d201a389211ffdc1a7c806/butterknife-ktx-compiler/src/main/java/com/bartoszlipinski/butterknifektx/KotlinCodeGenerator.kt#L49-L59) how I'm specifying a `receiver` of an extension function ("similar" use-case):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This worked - upvoted the answer. Will accept later unless a more elegant solution comes around. It works but does not really feel DRY..

Comment: @ligi can you provide a part of your `class`-generating code? Maybe there's a "DRYier" solution 